# How to transpose and divide by a number?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to transpose an array and divide the transposed output by a number for every single cell of the array.

**Example (not functional):**

```
=TRANSPOSE('1/3/2017'!O2:S2)/COUNTA('1/3/2017'!A2:A108)
```

[image]

Comment: I get what you are functionally asking for ( how to transpose the Array / not have a broken formula ), but I don't get what you are trying to achieve with those maths. What data is in O2:S2? Why do you need to divide each element of the O2:S2 transposed array by 107? Assuming the Value in O2 is "63" and the other elements are similiar, all the values in column F will be <1. `=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA('1/3/2017'!O2:S2/COUNTA('1/3/2017'!A2:A108)))`

Comment: @Xzila thank you for your hint! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You have to wrap TRANSPOSE inside the ARRAYFORMULA.

Example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE('1/3/2017'!O2:S2)/COUNTA('1/3/2017'!A2:A108))
```